# Caesar cipher in Ruby

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I must implement a simple [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) class. Initializer takes two parameters - number of positions to shift the alphabet (integer) and the alphabet used (as string, not necessarily the standard English alphabet). The class must have two instance methods `encrypt` and `decrypt`, which take a string and do the respective action based on the parameters of the initializer. These are my rspec tests:

```
describe "Caesar" do

  latin_encrypter = Caesar.new 4
  dna_encrypter = Caesar.new 3, 'ACTG'

  it 'encrypts correctly' do
    expect(latin_encrypter.encrypt 'hello').to eq "lipps"
  end

  it 'encrypts correctly using DNA alphabet' do
    expect(dna_encrypter.encrypt 'ACCTGA').to eq "GAACTG"
  end

  it 'decrypts correctly' do
    expect(latin_encrypter.decrypt 'lipps').to eq 'hello'
  end

  it 'decrypts correctly using DNA alphabet' do
    expect(dna_encrypter.decrypt 'GAACTG').to eq 'ACCTGA'
  end
end
```

and this is my implementation:

```
class Caesar
  def initialize(shift, alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    @shift = shift % alphabet.size
    @alphabet = alphabet
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    string.chars.map { |char| @alphabet[@alphabet.index(char) + @shift - @alphabet.size] }.join
  end

  def decrypt(string)
    string.chars.map { |char| @alphabet[@alphabet.index(char) - @shift] }.join
  end
end
```

Is this an optimal algorithm for encryption/decryption or is there a better one (perhaps using `gsub`)?

Comment: `Caesar.new(1).encrypt('1337')` → `NoMethodError: undefined method \`+' for nil:NilClass`. The parameter may be invalid, but the error message should be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has `tr`, a very efficient method for substituting one character to another. It does not error on "unknown" characters, like spaces etc. Using that, the Caesar class becomes:

```
class Caesar
  def initialize(shift, alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a.join)
    i = shift % alphabet.size #I like this
    @decrypt = alphabet
    @encrypt = alphabet[i..-1] + alphabet[0...i]
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    string.tr(@decrypt, @encrypt)
  end

  def decrypt(string)
    string.tr(@encrypt, @decrypt)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

The only (conceptual) problem I see in your code is that both `encrypt`/`decrypt` perform a O(n) operation (`detect`) for every character (so at then end it's a O(n*m) algorithm), that's unnecessarily inefficient. Build a hash object to use as an indexer:

```
class Caesar
  def initialize(shift, alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a.join)
    @shift = shift
    @alphabet = alphabet
    @indexes = alphabet.chars.map.with_index.to_h
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    string.chars.map { |c| @alphabet[(@indexes[c] + @shift) % @alphabet.size] }.join
  end

  def decrypt(string)
    string.chars.map { |c| @alphabet[(@indexes[c] - @shift) % @alphabet.size] }.join
  end
end
```

You can also build encrypter/decrypter hash tables at initialization:

```
class Caesar
  def initialize(shift, alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a.join)
    chars = alphabet.chars.to_a
    @encrypter = chars.zip(chars.rotate(shift)).to_h
    @decrypter = @encrypter.invert
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    @encrypter.values_at(*string.chars).join
  end

  def decrypt(string)
    @decrypter.values_at(*string.chars).join
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, `Array#rotate` was the thing I was looking for. Thank you very much! The second version is really elegant!

Answer (score -2):

Your code does not work with letters like "A..Z".
The following does:

```
puts "Text for encrypt please: "
text_for_encrypt = gets.chomp

puts "Input encrypt key: "
key = gets.chomp.to_i

text_arrow = text_for_encrypt.split('').to_a
alphabet_az = ("a".."z").to_a.join
alphabet_AZ = ("A".."Z").to_a.join
i = key % alphabet_az.size


encrypt_az = alphabet_az.chars.rotate(i).join
encrypt_AZ = alphabet_AZ.chars.rotate(i).join

res = []
text_arrow.each do |letter|
  if ("a".."z") === letter
    letter = letter.tr( alphabet_az, encrypt_az )
    res << letter
  else
    letter = letter.tr( alphabet_AZ, encrypt_AZ )
    res << letter
  end
end

puts "Your code: #{res.join}"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review! Please see: [How do I write a good answer?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), where you will find: "Every answer must make at least one insightful observation about the code in the question. Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers and may be deleted".